Jenkins server raises "Start request repeated too quickly." on startup
Software Versions



Software
Version




OS
Ubuntu 17.0.12


Java
OpenJDK 64-Bit (build 17.0.12+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu224.04, mixed mode, sharing)


Jenkins
2.470



Problem Statement
I am trying to start a Jenkins service using the following command
systemctl status jenkins

However, when I run the aforementioned command it raises an exception and returns an error code. The exception message says "Start request repeated too quickly".  I have included more detailed error information below.
Relevant Logs
× jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration ServerLoaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/
jenkins.service; enabled; preset: enabled)Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-08-03 
09:42:54 UTC; 6h agoProcess: 4368 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)Main PID:
 4368 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)CPU: 521ms

Aug 03 09:42:53 ip-172-31-0-123 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Main process exited, code=exited, 
status=1/FAILUREAug 03 09:42:53 ip-172-31-0-123 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 
'exit-code'.Aug 03 09:42:53 ip-172-31-0-123 systemd[1]: Failed to start jenkins.service - Jenkins 
Continuous Integration Server.Aug 03 09:42:54 ip-172-31-0-123 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Scheduled 
restart job, restart counter is at 5.Aug 03 09:42:54 ip-172-31-0-123 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: 
Start request repeated too quickly.Aug 03 09:42:54 ip-172-31-0-123 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: 
Failed with result 'exit-code'.Aug 03 09:42:54 ip-172-31-0-123 systemd[1]: Failed to start 
jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

This error message is a symptom of a currently unknown issue.  Your service is failing for some reason and the Linux service manager is trying to restart it too quickly.  However, what you care about is not solving the "restart too quickly" problem but the "why is it failing in the first place problem".  Run the following systemctl reset-failed jenkins.service then run  journalctl -u jenkins.service.  Some log info should print to the screen.  Update your question with that information.  If nothing displays run systemctl edit jenkins and set a log location, then cat the log

As a side note - I reviewed, edited, and accepted your first question.  Congratulations on your first approved question and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please take the time to read my review notes ( not the comment above, the review notes from the question itself ) and try to incorporate those suggestions in your next question or answer! Additionally, ChatGPT is usually my first stop and only when the two of us combined cannot solve the problem do I post on StackOverflow because by that time you will have a sufficiently strong understanding to ask a guided question.  Also search before posting

Similar problem with Jenkins. Running command journalctl -u jenkins.service (suggested by @Ranita Biswas) found out that Java 11 was no longer working with my Jenkins version and only 17 and 21 Java versions were supported so installing Java 17 fixed the problem.
